# uniform convegence of a sequence of sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm a beginner, so please be kind. Let $Q$ be a compact subset of a finite-dimensional normed vector space (e.g. a compact subset of $\mathbb R^n$). For each $i\in\mathbb N$, I have a sequence $(q_n^i)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of elements $q_n^i\in Q$, that converges to some $\bar q^i\in Q$.

I was wondering the following: By possibly considering subsequences $(q^i_{n_k})_k$ of $(q^i_n)_n$, for some $i\in\mathbb N$, can I say that there exists $K>0$ such that, for all $i\in\mathbb N$ and all $k\ge K$, $\|q^i_{n_k}-\bar q^i\|\le 2^{-i}$?

The reason I'm asking is the following: Since each sequence $(q^i_n)_n$ converges to $q^i$, there exists $N_i>0$ such that, for all $n\ge N_i$, we have $\|q_n^i-\bar q^i\|\le 2^{-i}$. Consider the sequence $(N_i)_{i\in\mathbb N}$, if $\sup_{i} N_i<\infty$ the result trivially holds without taking subsequences. Otherwise, pick $i^*$ arbitrarily in $\mathbb N$ and let $K=N_{i^*}$. Let $i\in\mathbb N$ be such that there exists $n\ge K$ such that $\|q^i_n-\bar q^i\|>2^{-i}$. The first thing that come into my mind was to consider a subsequence $(n_k)_k$ defined as $n_0=N_i$ and $n_k=n_{k-1}+1$ for all $k=1,2,\dots$. However I'm not sure this is going to work, since if $(N_i)_i$ is not bounded then I'm going to start my subsequences by taking as initial indexed numbers that are arbitrarily large... Can you suggest me something? Thanks

---- edit

another approach: Let $N_i$ be defined as above and, for each $n\in\mathbb N$, take a subsequence $(q^{i_k}_n)_n$ of the sequences $(q^i_n)_n$ such that $N_{i_{k+1}}\ge N_{i_{k}}$, and consider the sequences $(q^{i_k}_{N_k})_k$, then, for all $k\in\mathbb N$ I have $\|q^{i_k}_{N_k}-\bar q^{i_k}\|\le 2^{-i_k}$. Therefore even if "weaker", in this way I have a subsequence that satisfy such inequality uniformly in $k$. Is that correct?

Comment: You haven't used the compactness of $Q$. Formulate the convergence using open balls, to take a finite subfamily of them. Then use the minimal radius.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. In the meanwhile I added another workaround, I'm going to reason on your hint now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is negative even for a simple case $Q=\{0,1\}\subset\Bbb R$ and eventually constant sequences. For each natural $i$ and $n$ put $q^i_n=0$ if $n>i$, and $q^i_n=1$, otherwise. Then for each $i$ a sequence $(q^i_n)$ converges to $0=\bar q^i$. But for any sequence $(n_k)$ of natural numbers and any natural number $K$ holds $\|q_{n_K}^{n_K}- \bar q^{n_K}\|=1$.

Comment: hell, I see. Thanks a lot.